# How to reach to home page of the app when it is exited manually

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

How to start from the home page of a particular app which is exited in middle by clicking the device home page

Comment: Do you intend to send people to your apps home screen or opening screen instead of the devices homescreen when they push the button?

Answer (score 1):

if it is your app and you want the app to start from beginning after pressing home button ,you have to set a property in info.plist .the property is "Application does not run in background"
setting it to YES will solve the case.

TNQ

Answer (score 0):

there is a method in applicationdelegate like

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
}
```

u can use the code to set the view to your home page here